# GridLayoutManager in both orientations at once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Is it possible to override GridLayoutManager to be able to use it in both directions (vertical and horizontal) at once? (User can scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you can implement a custom `LayoutManager` yourself.
And you're in a bit of luck because [this tutorial](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/) (you will need to follow all three steps) basically creates exactly what you need.